# How to get the declaring class / trait using Scala reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Using Java reflection, I can make:

```scala
MyObject
  .getClass
  .getMethods
  .map(_.getDeclaringClass())
```

For each method declared in the Object `MyObject`, I will get the declaring class of that method / value - what I'm interest here is, specifically, in telling whether those methods / values are being declared by `MyObject` or not.

That said, I don't want to use Java reflection (because, among other things, I lose Scala features in the process - for instance, `getMethods` will return both methods and values, because the way values are represented in Java). How can I achieve the same with Scala reflection? This is what I've got so far:

```scala
val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val currentMirror = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
val instanceMirror = currentMirror.reflect(MyObject)
val moduleSymbol = currentMirror.moduleSymbol(MyObject.getClass)

val methodSymbols =  moduleSymbol
  .info
  .members
  .map(_.asMethod)

methodSymbols
  .map(_.getDeclaringClassInScala) // ???????
```

Of course, the last line won't work. I tried to browse the docs, to no avail. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: just to clarify, the question has been written in a more generic way in order to help more people. My use case, in particular, is filtering all the methods that have been declared directly by `MyObject`, instead of inherited by whatever other module or class.

Comment: As I stated, I don't want to use Java reflection because it does not differentiate between methods and values. I have achieved what I want with Java reflection - it is just that I need features it will not provide me, hence the search for the Scala reflection version.

Comment: I had seen that one. His problem is a bit different - he is also facing issues with Java reflection nature, but he wanted Java reflection nonetheless.

Comment: Have you seen [the owner method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Symbols$MethodSymbol.html#owner:Symbols.this.Symbol)?

Comment: Hell yeah, that is what I needed! It was kinda obvious but I didn't pay attention to that section of the doc.Thanks! I'm having a little issue, though: calling `.owner`, I get a `Symbol`. I have to compare it to a `ModuleSymbol`, and I don't really know how to do it. Anyway, can you write it down as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Doing `asType` returns a `TypeSymbol`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [owner](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Symbols%24MethodSymbol.html#owner:Symbols.this.Symbol) method should help you here. It'll return the enclosing class.

```
methodSymbols.map(_.owner.asType)
```

Example in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/C6LAuzTeQTOPuB09BvACuQ)

Comment: I'm already accepting it in advance. What I told you in the comments has literally that - doing `asType` returns a `TypeSymbol`. My module is not a type, so I cannot call `asType` on the module. I'm still trying to figure out how to compare a `moduleSymbol` with a `Symbol`.

Comment: @LucasLima The ModuleSymbol has me a bit confused. Are your methods inside an object or a class/trait?

Comment: @LucasLima Here is the Scastie I am using: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2HHjFshGQiKFJFHDqt7N2A

Comment: @LucasLima Do `.asTerm` instead of `.asType`. You'll have a `TermSymbol` and `ModuleSymbol`s are `TermSymbol`s.

Comment: Inside an object. Now I got it, though - I needed to make `methodSymbols.map(_.owner.asClass).filter(_ == currentMirror.symbolOf(MyObject))`.

Comment: Actually, `termSymbol` worked for the `moduleSymbol`, but not for the result of the `owner` function. Anyway, the `asClass` did the job. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1):

> My use case, in particular, is filtering all the methods that have been declared directly by `MyObject`, instead of inherited by whatever other module or class.

Then it's just enough to use `.decls` instead of `.members`

```
trait MyTrait1 {
  def bar(): Unit = println("bar")
}
trait MyClass {
  def baz(): Unit = println("baz")
}

object MyObject extends MyClass with MyTrait1 {
  def foo(): Unit = println("foo")
}

typeOf[MyObject.type].members.filter(_.isMethod).toList
// List(method foo, constructor MyObject, method bar, method $init$, method baz, method synchronized, method ##, method !=, method ==, method ne, method eq, method notifyAll, method notify, method clone, method getClass, method hashCode, method toString, method equals, method wait, method wait, method wait, method finalize, method asInstanceOf, method isInstanceOf)
typeOf[MyObject.type].decls.filter(_.isMethod).toList
// List(constructor MyObject, method foo)
```

So I guess there is no need in `methodSymbols.map(_.owner.asClass).filter(_ == currentMirror.symbolOf(MyObject))` (I guess you meant `symbolOf[MyObject.type]`).

`MyObject` can't inherit methods from other modules (objects), only from classes (traits).